# Light userdata as table keys

Tags: c, lua, embed

I'm working with Lua/C bindings and am having an issue with objects stored in a lua table that are light user data. In the example below, I'm calling 'myfunction' from C with some data that is then used to allocate a new object (in C) via my function "net.connection(v)", which uses 
lua_newuserdata() to return the object result. I try to use this value as a key into a table 'mytable'. When I call 'myfunction', create my new object, and store it in my table, it appears to be fine, as the value I store into the table is what the 'print' gives me.

```
mytable = {}

function action(obj)
  print(mytable[obj])
end

function myfunction(data)
  for k,v in pairs(data) do
    theObj = net.connection(v)
    mytable[theObj] = "test string"
    print(mytable[theObj]) --Prints 'test string'
  end
end
```

However, at a later point in time, I want to look up this data using the same object pointer (function 'action' above), but always get nil. The pointer addresses of (theObj and obj) are the same, and when I print out the contents of the table (keys, values) it appears that the table contains both a pointer to my userdata and the proper value, but when I use the argument (obj), I can't retrieve a value from the table. In the case of the function 'action', I'm pushing the user data onto the stack with push_lightuserdata.

Are there any subtleties to using push_lightuserdata in this way that could be causing this issue?

Accoring to [this](http://lua-users.org/wiki/LightUserData) link, using light user data as a table key is fine...

Comment: Just to clarify, when you do something like `for k, v in pairs(mytable) do print(k, v) end` you can see the key value pair you want, but when you call `action` with what appears to be the appropriate key, you get nil? Or are you trying to get to the value in `mytable` from C code not posted here?

Comment: You're correct. I can see the key, value pair I want when iterating over the table in 'action', but when I try to get the value using the parameter as the key it gives me a nil result.

Comment: Have you tried double checking the key with `print(obj)` directly inside `action` to make sure it's getting the value you expect? If there's not a lot of other key value pairs in the table, I might try adding something like this: `for k, v in pairs(mytable) do if k == obj then print(k, v, "Found it!") else print(k, v) end`. Using light user data as keys should be fine, so there has to be a silly mistake here somewhere. :-/

Comment: Yeah, I've done that, and get something like this:            (userdata: 0x6e8ca94)

userdata: 0x7c71704 test_string
userdata: 0x6e8ca94 test_string
userdata: 0x7c66434 test_string

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Userdata and light userdata are two distinct types in Lua. You are putting a userdata in the table as the key, and then trying to find it with a light userdata. That won't work. You need to use the same types.

Since you are creating the `net.connection` as a userdata, you'll need to keep it in a table somewhere so you can find it later from C.

Comment: This helps a lot. However, I'm still a bit confused about how to go about solving this issue. How might I go about re-implementing the above example to make it work? If userdata and light userdata are distinct types, how can I invoke a callback with anything but light userdata? Is that possible?

Comment: There are several ways to keep userdata pointers so that they are accessible from your C code. One way is to out them in the registry indexed by an integer or light userdata. A safer way (to avoid registry bloat and key conflicts) is to store them in an upvalue of a function (or all functions if they share closures) of your C library. See: http://www.lua.org/pil/27.3.3.html